# Ruby on Rails: just upgraded to rails 3. some of my links don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the link:

```
    <li><%= link_to "Map", :controller => :info, :action => :map  %></li>
```

routes:

```
  resources :link_pages
  resources :services  
  resource :user_session
  resource :account, :controller => "users"
  resources :password_resets
  resources :users
  resources :addresses
  resources :info

  match "/home", :to => 'info#home'
  match "/register", :to => 'users#new'

  root :to => 'info#home'
```

but when I click "Map", it thinks I want to go to info#show =\

```
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<%= link_to "Map", {:controller => :info, :action => :map}  %>` (notice the Hash)